# Crash problem Unknown situation

Tags: iphone, cocoa, crash

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                0x33a06466 0x33a03000 + 13414
1   Foundation                     0x302eedf6 0x302ce000 + 134646
2   CoreFoundation                 0x3044509c 0x303ee000 + 356508
3   CoreFoundation                 0x30444b54 0x303ee000 + 355156
4   CoreFoundation                 0x304161ae 0x303ee000 + 164270
5   CoreFoundation                 0x30415c80 0x303ee000 + 162944
6   CoreFoundation                 0x30415b88 0x303ee000 + 162696
7   GraphicsServices               0x31eec4a4 0x31ee8000 + 17572
8   GraphicsServices               0x31eec550 0x31ee8000 + 17744
9   UIKit                          0x313cf322 0x31398000 + 226082
10  UIKit                          0x313cce8c 0x31398000 + 216716
11  MyApp                          0x00002c6c 0x1000 + 7276
12  MyApp                          0x00002c20 0x1000 + 7200

Thread 1:
0   libSystem.B.dylib              0x310bf974 0x31092000 + 186740
1   libSystem.B.dylib              0x31169704 0x31092000 + 882436
2   libSystem.B.dylib              0x31169174 0x31092000 + 881012
3   libSystem.B.dylib              0x31168b98 0x31092000 + 879512
4   libSystem.B.dylib              0x3110d24a 0x31092000 + 504394
5   libSystem.B.dylib              0x31105970 0x31092000 + 473456

Thread 2:
0   libSystem.B.dylib              0x3110d9e0 0x31092000 + 506336
1   libSystem.B.dylib              0x3110d364 0x31092000 + 504676
2   libSystem.B.dylib              0x31105970 0x31092000 + 473456

Thread 3:
0   libSystem.B.dylib              0x31093268 0x31092000 + 4712
1   libSystem.B.dylib              0x31095354 0x31092000 + 13140
2   CoreFoundation                 0x30416648 0x303ee000 + 165448
3   CoreFoundation                 0x30415ed2 0x303ee000 + 163538
4   CoreFoundation                 0x30415c80 0x303ee000 + 162944
5   CoreFoundation                 0x30415b88 0x303ee000 + 162696
6   WebCore                        0x35b32124 0x35a7b000 + 749860
7   libSystem.B.dylib              0x3110c886 0x31092000 + 501894
8   libSystem.B.dylib              0x31101a88 0x31092000 + 457352

Thread 4:
0   libSystem.B.dylib              0x31093268 0x31092000 + 4712
1   libSystem.B.dylib              0x31095354 0x31092000 + 13140
2   CoreFoundation                 0x30416648 0x303ee000 + 165448
3   CoreFoundation                 0x30415ed2 0x303ee000 + 163538
4   CoreFoundation                 0x30415c80 0x303ee000 + 162944
5   CoreFoundation                 0x30415b88 0x303ee000 + 162696
6   Foundation                     0x302fb5f6 0x302ce000 + 185846
7   Foundation                     0x302d9192 0x302ce000 + 45458
8   Foundation                     0x302d2242 0x302ce000 + 16962
9   libSystem.B.dylib              0x3110c886 0x31092000 + 501894
10  libSystem.B.dylib              0x31101a88 0x31092000 + 457352

Thread 5:
0   libSystem.B.dylib              0x310b768c 0x31092000 + 153228
1   CoreFoundation                 0x3044d662 0x303ee000 + 390754
2   libSystem.B.dylib              0x3110c886 0x31092000 + 501894
3   libSystem.B.dylib              0x31101a88 0x31092000 + 457352

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00163b70    r1: 0x0006eb67      r2: 0x00163b70      r3: 0x0006eb67
    r4: 0x08d391f8    r5: 0x00000000      r6: 0x00114b50      r7: 0x2fdfeb08
    r8: 0x00114c10    r9: 0x00000002     r10: 0x08d87fb0     r11: 0x00000000
    ip: 0x00043319    sp: 0x2fdfeae8      lr: 0x00043341      pc: 0x33a06466
  cpsr: 0x08000030

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -    0x7ffff +FaceTime armv7  <effbfce4a5323305ed4e2b8ff9cfba1e> /var/mobile/Applications/C83336A3-95FB-41C4-BD8A-F38954A8320A/FaceTime.app/FaceTime
  0x25a000 -   0x25bfff  dns.so armv7  <fcefecb2d5e095ba88127eec3af57ec0> /usr/lib/info/dns.so
0x2fe00000 - 0x2fe27fff  dyld armv7  <06e6959cebb4a72e66c833e26ae64d26> /usr/lib/dyld
0x30040000 - 0x30043fff  ActorKit armv7  <f5d038591e564646e9237a59c6c14293> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ActorKit.framework/ActorKit
0x30044000 - 0x30047fff  ApplePushService armv7  <9d1eb7b11f0f146c941efbab2c055606> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
0x30048000 - 0x30088fff  CoreAudio armv7  <f32e03ee4c68f0db23f05afc9a3cc94c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x30089000 - 0x30092fff  ITSync armv7  <87d409553f90e41a01afce047dc2e8fe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ITSync.framework/ITSync
0x30093000 - 0x30093fff  vecLib armv7  <e53d234e808c77d286161095f92c58cf> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x30094000 - 0x30095fff  DataMigration armv7  <babbc72d4d48325de147d5103d7bc00d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x30096000 - 0x300a9fff  MediaControl armv7  <874e83896424ebb3afe59a3a59ba4dfe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaControl.framework/MediaControl
0x300aa000 - 0x301cafff  CoreGraphics armv7  <2d7b40a7baca915ce78b1dd9a0d6433b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x301d6000 - 0x3020bfff  ImageCapture armv7  <11cb11dea0b6910987518cfb7dfa7ba1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ImageCapture.framework/ImageCapture
0x3020c000 - 0x30212fff  IAP armv7  <134f59ad5bb91bab6a5fe21b6f36dc8b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IAP.framework/IAP
0x302a2000 - 0x302cbfff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <54484a513761868149405df7fc29b5c0> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x302ce000 - 0x303edfff  Foundation armv7  <81d36041f04318cb51db5aafed9ce504> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x303ee000 - 0x304d4fff  CoreFoundation armv7  <01441e01f5141a50ee723362e59ca400> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x305fb000 - 0x30631fff  CoreLocation armv7  <e19b7aa132318fc90618a663bd576461> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x306a6000 - 0x306fffff  EventKit armv7  <037c4bb5e2529e6004d0e1f3d95a84cc> /System/Library/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/EventKit
0x3078e000 - 0x307cdfff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <a7c117c92607a512823d307b8fdd0151> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x307f9000 - 0x30816fff  AppleAccount armv7  <e3833276f8877499c8dd76b3b3d88501> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleAccount.framework/AppleAccount
0x308c2000 - 0x308f5fff  QuickLook armv7  <8c54395accc7ffc84766ff3e9b24beb1> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/QuickLook
0x308f6000 - 0x309e1fff  PhotoLibrary armv7  <ae1e7ac429fc2c53c203132ba5e8e922> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibrary.framework/PhotoLibrary
0x309e2000 - 0x309e5fff  ArtworkCache armv7  <1e65b5000a2234b69164e7904fcf826b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ArtworkCache.framework/ArtworkCache
0x309e6000 - 0x309eefff  MobileBluetooth armv7  <6d6c62f52219d27be50f1d7c39a68dc6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileBluetooth.framework/MobileBluetooth
0x309ef000 - 0x30a22fff  AddressBook armv7  <7c87e0175c8649d6832419da8a1cfac1> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x30a23000 - 0x30a43fff  PrintKit armv7  <02a9c6f4173a0673c4637a3b570345cd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x30aa3000 - 0x30af3fff  GMM armv7  <2b63c1e1ce647e031a8a491e156f04d3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GMM.framework/GMM
0x30e64000 - 0x30eabfff  MessageUI armv7  <bb7d161bb6c699afb2e1744ece115ae8> /System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI
0x30fc2000 - 0x30fd4fff  iAd armv7  <a57f002be6ce2e0d048f770190af9b15> /System/Library/Frameworks/iAd.framework/iAd
0x30fd5000 - 0x31082fff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <3f2df600942dc72aad312b3cc98ec479> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x31092000 - 0x311a3fff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <138a43ab528bb428651e6aa7a2a7293c> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x311af000 - 0x312cffff  libmecabra.dylib armv7  <b2293b8acb00a14bace7520a63f39439> /usr/lib/libmecabra.dylib
0x312d0000 - 0x31312fff  CoreTelephony armv7  <96d3af505b9f2887e62c7e99c157733e> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x31340000 - 0x31373fff  iCalendar armv7  <6eb50e720d642f5ac510a36989b276b2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iCalendar.framework/iCalendar
0x31398000 - 0x31719fff  UIKit armv7  <de1cbd3219a74e4d41b30428f428e223> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x31722000 - 0x3174afff  StoreServices armv7  <f409aaf487bd7e7a08c77ba5a2a83a1a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreServices.framework/StoreServices
0x3174b000 - 0x31764fff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <ee16b5cee12a8947c8e511ed51ae7fef> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x3177f000 - 0x317b5fff  CoreText armv7  <b9b5c21b2d2a28abc47842c78c026ddf> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x3180a000 - 0x318b3fff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <b3d82f80a777cb1434052ea2d232e3df> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x318b4000 - 0x318e0fff  DataAccess armv7  <6b9b5235b449335ce5c66d53f32004cd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccess.framework/DataAccess
0x31923000 - 0x31938fff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <ea156820997ae9a2baf664d0f79f18d7> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x31939000 - 0x31949fff  TelephonyUI armv7  <4d181ff2cf0373cf56db350e0fbc1717> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TelephonyUI.framework/TelephonyUI
0x3194a000 - 0x3194cfff  SpringBoardUI armv7  <42a6b76dddc6c6aa515f27dd11f5957a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardUI.framework/SpringBoardUI
0x3194d000 - 0x3195dfff  DataAccessExpress armv7  <6767a1e2afbc86a1ec63dd784f5d3677> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x31971000 - 0x31980fff  Notes armv7  <7d7a3d10a349471cd2757a479d131b31> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Notes.framework/Notes
0x31981000 - 0x31a0afff  Message armv7  <69cb7cb1d1d7865fc04dc341544174b6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Message.framework/Message
0x31a0b000 - 0x31a9efff  ImageIO armv7  <5b5a294d4250eff866fdbf891b1e8b34> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x31ab8000 - 0x31b34fff  AVFoundation armv7  <4c7356c795e01bd5c21b00a409a07476> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
0x31b35000 - 0x31b3afff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <cec3f3271fc267c32c169ed03e312d63> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x31b3b000 - 0x31b64fff  ContentIndex armv7  <247576cb4f1ff8e92650ae3cb4973760> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ContentIndex.framework/ContentIndex
0x31cb5000 - 0x31d56fff  Celestial armv7  <b411f4662383ec24dbfbcde8f4c23d67> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x31d59000 - 0x31d61fff  libkxld.dylib armv7  <854e82fe66feef01e54c7c8a209851ac> /usr/lib/system/libkxld.dylib
0x31d62000 - 0x31dd1fff  ProofReader armv7  <d2e62a8ab7e1460c7f6de8913c703e6d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x31de0000 - 0x31ee7fff  CoreData armv7  <29b1ab7d339e42a6ff6923e54cf43e7b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x31ee8000 - 0x31ef4fff  GraphicsServices armv7  <0099670dccd99466653956bf918d667a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x31ff5000 - 0x32002fff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <0f4e595e6eb2170aceb729f32b5de8c2> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x32003000 - 0x3229dfff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <2e77d87e96af938aacf0a6008e6fb89d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x322e7000 - 0x32316fff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <3f982c11b5526fc39a92d585c60d8a90> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x323f9000 - 0x3242afff  VideoToolbox armv7  <bb7ff9014b1dabec2acce95d41f05b59> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x3242b000 - 0x324ecfff  RawCamera armv7  <b7f53a8a4a1188746c9c3d818f28795b> /System/Library/CoreServices/RawCamera.bundle/RawCamera
0x324ed000 - 0x3259cfff  WebKit armv7  <644a1c6120578f896bed7121307aa2af> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x32644000 - 0x32687fff  ManagedConfiguration armv7  <27ac7f05482a8aa9977150f34f9be6eb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x326ae000 - 0x32764fff  MapKit armv7  <69921a6353270a6f77e0816d636812e8> /System/Library/Frameworks/MapKit.framework/MapKit
0x32765000 - 0x3276efff  WebBookmarks armv7  <9f1760206eaef20c605c5d98e45c823e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebBookmarks.framework/WebBookmarks
0x3278a000 - 0x3279dfff  libmis.dylib armv7  <855aefc263c6c20e6cf8723ea36125a2> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x3279e000 - 0x327a6fff  MobileWiFi armv7  <b29d4c5e300ef81060e38f72bb583c02> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x327a7000 - 0x328e0fff  AudioToolbox armv7  <657b327f2ceee9f22f9474f2f9bddbe6> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x3290a000 - 0x32947fff  CoreMedia armv7  <4ea4d349e886206d1ecf5bae870f3f04> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x3297b000 - 0x32981fff  ProtocolBuffer armv7  <7e279d3b6d1e1fd7dc8c8a883255fa17> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x32987000 - 0x329a8fff  MobileSync armv7  <cff20dfe818febca9f3232426d59a42d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSync.framework/MobileSync
0x329af000 - 0x329b2fff  CertUI armv7  <5f37446c6b65a8c38ab6233c2e33da66> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CertUI.framework/CertUI
0x32a10000 - 0x32a12fff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <1040629f37795146c9dcac8ab1a868fc> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x32a68000 - 0x32a74fff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <137b75e19b2450c234dec88d538798ff> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x32a88000 - 0x32bc5fff  MediaToolbox armv7  <a18bbcc41a38917fe0ae5e183d3f6b07> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x32c80000 - 0x32c8efff  DataDetectorsCore armv7  <31929ee8505b90fb51d269cd4763f2e8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsCore.framework/DataDetectorsCore
0x32c8f000 - 0x32c93fff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <e861a330d14702f148ca5133dcbe954c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x32ca7000 - 0x32ca9fff  MobileInstallation armv7  <8e6b0d9f642be06729ffdaaee97053b0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x32caa000 - 0x32cb5fff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <fabaddbcbc8c02bab0261df9d78e0e25> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x32cba000 - 0x32cc9fff  MobileDeviceLink armv7  <8f2fc7e811bc57f7a09d7df81c329e1a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDeviceLink.framework/MobileDeviceLink
0x32ccb000 - 0x32cd8fff  OpenGLES armv7  <a12565ffb5bb42e3019f1957cd4951d0> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x32cda000 - 0x32cdffff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  <5f73c7138ee1cb7103a98aec99f9ed88> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x32d17000 - 0x32d1dfff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <5bbd9b3f5cfece328f80c403a8805ce9> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x32d1e000 - 0x32d69fff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <251c5ac7380802a16e30d827c027c637> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x32d6a000 - 0x32e18fff  QuartzCore armv7  <83a8e5f0033369e437069c1e758fed83> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x32e19000 - 0x32f2ffff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <e7fbb2ac586567e574dc33d7bb5c4dc9> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x32f5b000 - 0x32f5efff  CaptiveNetwork armv7  <a2af7147f5538d7669b14fa7b19b5a7c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x32f5f000 - 0x3301efff  CFNetwork armv7  <02fe0e30e54fffdcbbbd02e8cb812c3a> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x33026000 - 0x33054fff  MIME armv7  <1989502ce4da514314647c6a0098d8e7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MIME.framework/MIME
0x330c3000 - 0x330fbfff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <374bd566263e8929c10d50d6a6a48a46> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x330fd000 - 0x33106fff  CoreVideo armv7  <2092d5deb6b234e04678b7c1878ccd81> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x33128000 - 0x33135fff  DataDetectorsUI armv7  <a7e33ab2817110626fa1c5c731419101> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsUI.framework/DataDetectorsUI
0x3314b000 - 0x33195fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <53a6e7239c3908fa8c2915b65ff3b056> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x3319e000 - 0x331a1fff  IOSurface armv7  <deff02882166bf16d0765d68f0542cc8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x331a2000 - 0x331a4fff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <3f0b58ea13d30f0cdb73f6ffe6d4e75c> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x331bd000 - 0x334cdfff  GeoServices armv7  <f6d9eba833e82b1a9a84b38ab7672012> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
0x334db000 - 0x33528fff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <55038e5c1d4d0dbdd94295e8cad7a9a4> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x33890000 - 0x338c2fff  AppSupport armv7  <47c8055ac99f187174ca373b702ffa68> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x338c3000 - 0x338cafff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <2989ea7a5cad2cfe91bd632b041d0ff4> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x339bf000 - 0x339f9fff  IOKit armv7  <eb932cc42d60e55d9a4d0691bcc3d9ad> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x33a03000 - 0x33ac4fff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <aaf5671a35f9ac20d5846703dafaf4c6> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x33aeb000 - 0x33aedfff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  <e66758bcda6da5d7f9b54fa5c4de6da2> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x33aee000 - 0x33b43fff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <9365fc6cae1bff737257e74faf3b1f26> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x33b4f000 - 0x33c3cfff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <c72b45f471df092dbd849081f7a3ef53> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x33ca7000 - 0x35620fff  TextInput armv7  <557601a7d93124fd5860606f294e900a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInput.framework/TextInput
0x35621000 - 0x35621fff  Accelerate armv7  <29dd5f17440bbb6e8e42e11b6fceda9a> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x35625000 - 0x35717fff  MusicLibrary armv7  <34edbee423aa7e2ea32ad4eed0620b85> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MusicLibrary.framework/MusicLibrary
0x3576d000 - 0x35770fff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <3a385ed495379116abbe50bc8cd5a612> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x35836000 - 0x3591efff  libGLProgrammability.dylib armv7  <1f478a71783cd7eb4ae9ef6f2dcea803> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLProgrammability.dylib
0x35936000 - 0x35a45fff  MediaPlayer armv7  <9337abd4fdd749473efaefe64ee649a0> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaPlayer.framework/MediaPlayer
0x35a46000 - 0x35a48fff  CrashReporterSupport armv7  <30a5f1edcdb9ffe868a620199a4cbe12> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x35a49000 - 0x35a53fff  AccountSettings armv7  <19c79f81d5d55fe2e6b618fcdc28258e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x35a5e000 - 0x35a5ffff  CoreSurface armv7  <f7caaf43609cfe0e475dfe83790edb4d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x35a61000 - 0x35a63fff  Camera armv7  <72ac72d4c09246d0774cda087069fb26> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Camera.framework/Camera
0x35a64000 - 0x35a7afff  EAP8021X armv7  <36659ec2b9def7b5798a05327e369247> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x35a7b000 - 0x36063fff  WebCore armv7  <d6bd9cf88ee82ab6b0e33e0ae1190772> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x36064000 - 0x36083fff  Bom armv7  <0f5fd6057bad5e1677869500d636821f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x3608d000 - 0x36094fff  AggregateDictionary armv7  <71372c95d4af7af787d0682a939e40ac> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x36097000 - 0x3612dfff  AddressBookUI armv7  <45665471fd70b0733b206d8166df74ef> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x3612e000 - 0x36140fff  PersistentConnection armv7  <cd2a699aa5036bdad0517603ba4db839> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x36141000 - 0x36178fff  Security armv7  <cd28e102950634ae7167ddee9c686d36> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
```

I dont understand this log pls any one help me

Comment: @Mitch I don't think he is...

Comment: You need to symbolicate your crash log, Amit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports

Answer (score 3):

You need to symbolicate the crash log. If you don't know how to do that, give it a quick google, there's also a great WWDC '10 session on this which you can download through iTunes. Symbolicating your crash log will change this from gibberish to something readable. Post the symbolicated log, then we can help you.

Comment: "Symbolicate" just sounds like a made up word, so I thought you were being sarcastic at first.  ;)